# How to "invert" a rule

Tags: replacement, rule, head

The subject is a bit cryptic, I know, but here is what I'd like to do: Let's say I am solving an ODE like this:

```
s = DSolve[{x'[t] == 1, y'[t] == x[t] t, x[0] == x0, 
   y[0] == y0}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

which gives

```
{{x(t)->t+x0,y(t)->1/6 (2 t^3+3 t^2 x0+6 y0)}}
```

I could then apply the new rule to the second one that comes out of the `DSolve` to obtain `y[t]` as a function of `x[t]`.

Now I'd like to convert the first of the replacement rules with one that replaces `t`, so the rule should look like this:

```
t -> -x0 + x[t]
```

I think the way to accomplish this would be to convert the Head `Rule` of my first rule to an `Equal`, and feed that into `Solve`. I tried to do that, but I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Solve[Hold[s[[1, 1, 1]]] == s[[1, 1, 2]], t] // ReleaseHold
```

One needs the `Hold` because without it `Solve` will not work with `x[t]`.

EDIT:
Another way would be

```
Solve[(Equal @@@ Flatten[s])[[1]] /. x[t] -> xt, t] /. xt -> x[t]
```

this works more like the OP suggested by "replacing" the rules of `s` by equations. The problem with that however is that I do not know how to get `Solve` to work with implicit functions like `x[t]`, this is why I needed those two replacements.

In general the issue with both solutions will be expressions like `x[t]` for both methods it would be nice to find an automatic solution for this. Maybe there is a way to tell solve to see all expressions just as variables not as functions but I have not found one.

Comment: Of course! I was hell-bent on using a rule to replace the `->` with a `==`, but I can just do it manually as you did. Thanks!